# Multipart/form-data with ajax don't work

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I'm trying to emulate a multipart/form-data POST form using AJAX and it doesn't work and I don't know why. I have reviewed the traffic a normal request sends (pressing the "submit" button) and my request and can't tell any difference. However, the receiving page insist in not detecting the ajax POST. What's going wrong??

Here is my form:

```
<code>
<html>
<script>
// http://www.w3schools.com/ajax
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{ // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{ // code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

function submitThis( action_page )
{
    var boundary1; 

    boundary1 = '-----------------------------' + makeid(); 
    xmlhttp.open("POST", action_page, false );
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader( 'Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data; boundary=' + boundary1 );

    myPostData = "";
    myPostData = myPostData + boundary1 + '\r\n';
    myPostData = myPostData + 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="textarea_post"' + '\r\n\r\n';
    myPostData = myPostData + 'message1' + '\r\n';
    myPostData = myPostData + boundary1 + '--\r\n';
    xmlhttp.send( myPostData );
} // submitThis

// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349404/generate-a-string-of-5-random-characters-in-javascript
function makeid()
{
    var text = "";
    var possible = "0123456789abcdef";

    for( var i=0; i < 16; i++ )
        text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));

    return text;
}

</script>
<body>

<h1>Pruebas de iframe</h1>

<form action="test_ajax_post.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<textarea cols="80" name="textarea_post">message1</textarea><br>
<iframe name="iframe_post" width="80%" src="quixote.html">
</iframe><br>
<input type="submit"><br>
<input type="button" value="Send with ajax" onclick="submitThis('test_ajax_post.php')"/>
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

And here is the page who receives the data "test_ajax_post.html" (pretty simple, tough):

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
echo "Textarea value: " . $_POST["textarea_post"] . "<br>";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

**The problem is** that the response when I click the "submit" button is this:

```
<html>
<body>
Textarea value: message1<br></body>
</html>
```

and when I click the 'Send with ajax' button is this (after sniffing it with fiddler):

```
<html>
<body>
Textarea value: <br></body>
</html>
```

**The value of the textarea is missing.** I've checked the result, 
almost bit by bit, and I can't tell any difference. What am I doing wrong?

Note: using jQuery or a framework is not an option, because I want modify this to post the content of an iFRAME also. This was the first step in something else.

More info: the server is a Windows 2003 running php version 5.3.10. Okay, it is not the best scenario, but I think that the problem is not there. As a client I've used Chrome and Internet Explorer 8.

Comment: looks like you may be overwriting your myPostData.  try myPostdata= for the first line and then myPostData .= for the rest.

Comment: @Jim, OP is concatenating each line with the previous contents of `myPostData` so that part is fine

Comment: The quote of the variable 'message1' is because I was lazy to put the proper content of the textarea. But despite of that, there is no value received at all

Comment: +1 just because you took your time and posted your output rather than just posting _don't work_

Comment: Sorry, I had an error in the text of my question and I've pasted the code of the first html twice

Comment: Have you looked at this question [Sending POST data with a XMLHttpRequest](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9713058/sending-post-data-with-a-xmlhttprequest)

Comment: Someboyd have pointed out this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9713058/sending-post-data-with-a-xmlhttprequest. I have to say that I didn't check it out at first glance, but I've done this just now: doesn't work.
I think that the problem is that I want to send a multipart/form-data, and in the example of the link, is a "normal" post form. They are not the same case. I want to do this stuff with a multipart because the next part of my evil plan is to upload the contents of an iframe.

Comment: Hi, did you try to using `FormData` instead of manually creating the data and setting the content-type? Example: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Using_FormData_Objects scroll down to "Retrieving a FormData object from an HTML form".

Comment: Agash, I will check it right now. thanks. I'll keep you posted

Comment: Sure, just keep in mind, don't set the content-type by yourself, FormData is automatically posted as Mulitpart-Form

Comment: In that case, I have to make the whole example, with the Blob, to force FormData to use multipart. I've done this (sorry but this comment box is very little to publish all the code) and it is very funny: it sends a complete multipart form, perfect, but... the results of the PHP page again show nothing. Value of the text area: empty, and value of the file empty also.